# Getting these two errors when I delete a project and system.DateTime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I need help with this issue. I am trying to delete a contract from my web application but when I delete it I get this error I used ASP.NET MVC 5 to design this web application:

[image]

I keep getting this error for System.DateTime:

[image]

Comment: Friend, please post the actual error stack, not just incomplete snapshots. The error you encounter deleting the contract has to do with referential integrity. You have other records referencing the one you are trying to delete and cascade deletes are not enabled. Can't help you without knowing the details. On the second one, your field is of type `string` and you are trying to assign a `Date` to it. You need to cast it.

Comment: Hi: Thanks for sharing possible solution. I don't know what code to post since the code is really big and cannot post all of it here that's why posted screenshot. for the second one I am trying to assign a Date to it but I don't know somehow getting this error below in screenshot. @JuanR

Comment: Please ask about *one* issue per post, and always post code as text rather than as a screenshot. Even if you don't know exactly what code to post, you could have posted the same amount of code as you took a screenshot of, but as text...

Comment: @Jolly We need to know the relationships between the tables. Clearly, something is referencing the record, but we don't know what because the information is not available. We don't know what the entity with the date issue looks like, but it's clear the `ModifiedDate` field is of type `string`. I am curious as to why you decided to make it a `string` if it's meant to hold a `Date`?

Comment: will do @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0):

I need more information on the first error, it looks like you're deleting something that is referenced to another table so it will have a foreign key constraint. The references of the item you are deleting will need to be removed from the other tables first.

2nd issue you need to a `System.DateTime` to a `string`, so you can do:

```
db.Entry(hR).Entity.ModifiedDate = LoginInfo.CurrentDate().ToString();
```

a better way of doing date time:

```
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Now; - local time
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow; - utc time
```

Then add your ToString();

You can also format DateTime depending on what you are after:
[DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thanks for sharing and it did solve the issue for second one thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Jolly While it may have solved the compiler issue, I think you should think about why ran into this issue in the first place. You are storing a `Date` value as a string. Perhaps you should consider changing the field to be of type `DateTime`?

Comment: The reason I wanted to keep only Date was because I want to keep the record of when the document was modified and for that I needed ModifiesDate but the issue with this is resolved theissue now. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jolly I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.